# Trying to connect Filezilla with SFTP

Tags: server, ssh, sftp, filezilla

I'm trying to connect with Filezilla to a SFTP Server using username and password, but I can't establish one (error message below).

I'm using:

- Filezilla in *Ubuntu 18.04 LTS*.
- External Server is setup with Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS. No control over it.

My connection settings in Filezilla:

[image]

```
Server: [IP adress]
Protocol: SFTP
Connection type: normal
user: [username]
password: [password]
```

The connection works with SSH and SFTP (from command line).

```
sftp username@ipadress
ssh username@ipadress
```

As far as I understand, the error message below, Filezilla uses *SSH-2.0-FileZilla_3.28.0* while the Ubuntu 14.04 server uses *SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8*.

I get this error:

```
Status: Verbinde mit [SERVER_IP]...
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CSftpConnectOpData::Send() in state 0
Trace:  Going to execute /usr/bin/fzsftp
Antwort:    fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
Trace:  CSftpConnectOpData::ParseResponse() in state 0
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CSftpConnectOpData::Send() in state 3
Befehl: open "username@[SERVER_IP]" 22
Trace:  Connecting to [SERVER_IP] port 22
Trace:  We claim version: SSH-2.0-FileZilla_3.28.0
Trace:  Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
Trace:  We believe remote version has SSH-2 channel request bug
Trace:  Using SSH protocol version 2
Trace:  Doing ECDH key exchange with curve Curve25519 and hash SHA-256
Trace:  Server also has ecdsa-sha2-nistp256/ssh-dss/ssh-rsa host keys, but we don't know any of them
Trace:  Host key fingerprint is:
Trace:  ssh-ed25519 256 [fingerprint] [weird_stuff]
```

Any idea, how I can connect?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Could you edit question and add your SFTP client setup in Filezilla & CLI? (*remove login info before posting*). Also be aware that Ubuntu 14.04 reached EOL.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @user.dz! I know that ubuntu 14.04 is far from up to date - sadly I have no control about what software runs on the server. I have updated my question and include any information I have til now. If you need more information, I would be happy if you can provide help how to get them. Thanks!

Comment: Well the trace log doesn't show any error, There should be more lines? Did you get key verification dialog on first connection? Settings in first tab seems ok, Filezilla tried port 22 by default. Check 2nd tab, if remote folder is configured, It should be a path that your user has access to.

Comment: The server version of OpenSSH-server is out-of date. We gently recommend that you cease using that server until the admin brings it's security up to date. Knowingly connecting to a server that is running an obsolete server stack is quite unwise.

Comment: @user.dz yes, the trace log doesn't show any error, that's what I thought, too! I didn't get any dialog and it is the whole trace log, no more lines. in the second tab all fields are empty (default settings).

Comment: @user535733 thanks for this information, do you have any details about that? the point is, that the server is from a client and I'm only a web developer. I need at least some details on what could happen and how risky this security leek is, before I can run to my boss and tell him about that. Even if my boss will agree, I don't know if and when the server get an update. Do you have any advice on how to connect to the server until the admin updates? I have to work with that server, if i like it or not... :(

Comment: @Micha simply tell them that you don't develop for obsolete/insecure releases, because you have your reputation to protect. You should insist on a secure, stable platform to work upon.

Comment: @Micha, Go Settings, Debug then enable more verbose level. Restart Filezilla client and try reconnect. Update the post afterward

Comment: @Micha to get more debug information you can also open an ssh session with high output details (in english please): `LANG=en_GB.UTF-8; ssh -vvv user@host` - You can also connect to sftp using Nautilus `nautilus 'sftp://user@host'`